# When I import the yaml from swagger the authorizer does not work, after removing and re-adding it , it works

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, swagger-2.0

I use custom authorizer and api gateway to athorize the user before calling my services. First I manually create all the resources and methods then I create the authorizer and attach the services to authorizer in method execution.
when I deploy my api gateway everything works fine and when I export the yaml file with api gateway extention I have the following yaml file

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
 version: "2017-06-02T19:36:38Z"
 title: "test"
 host: "t8ksrbnwce.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
 basePath: "/rrr"
 schemes:
  - "https"
 paths:
   /stories/{storyid}:
   get:
  produces:
  - "application/json"
  parameters:
  - name: "storyid"
    in: "path"
    required: true
    type: "string"
  responses:
    200:
      description: "200 response"
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
      headers:
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
          type: "string"
  security:
  - userAthenticationCheck: []
  x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
    responses:
      default:
        statusCode: "200"
        responseParameters:
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
    requestParameters:
      integration.request.path.id: "method.request.path.storyid"
    uri: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{id}"
    passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
    httpMethod: "GET"
    type: "http"
options:
  consumes:
  - "application/json"
  produces:
  - "application/json"
  responses:
    200:
      description: "200 response"
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
      headers:
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
          type: "string"
        Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
          type: "string"
        Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
          type: "string"
  x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
    responses:
      default:
        statusCode: "200"
        responseParameters:
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 
   "'GET,OPTIONS'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-
         Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,Access-Control-
  Allow-Headers,Origin,X-Requested-With,Accept,authorizationToken'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
    requestTemplates:
      application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
    passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
    type: "mock"
    securityDefinitions:
    userAthenticationCheck:
     type: "apiKey"
     name: "authorizationToken"
    in: "header"
   x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: "custom"
    x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
  authorizerUri: "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-
   31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-
 1:048947288163:function:Authorizer/invocations"
  authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 0
  type: "token"
  definitions:
  Empty:
    type: "object"
    title: "Empty Schema"
```

Now that I have the yaml file I want to import it anytime I need it.
However when I import the yaml file again, when I use postman to try the imported API gateway I get cors 500 error. Then when I delete the authorizer in  the authorizer section of api gateway and create it again with the same name, then it starts working again. But the problem is I need to automate this process and I do not want to manually remove and add the authorizer again. Can anyone help how to fix this? is it a bug in aws? Or am I missing sth?

Comment: The indentation is wrong. Are the indents actually like this, or is it just a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: @Helen it is just copy and paste in the yamle file the indentation is correct

Comment: I replied on the AWS forum post.

Answer (score 1):

apologies you are facing this issue.

There is a bug right now that is causing references to existing authorizers to be broken on imports. I'm not sure exactly if it affects all use cases or a subset, but clearly it's affecting you. We are working on getting this fix out as soon as possible.

Thanks,
Jack